The intersection of linear spaces
Let linear subspaces $A,B,C \subseteq \mathbb{F}_2^{n}$. Then, does it hold the following equation?
$$ (A + B) \cap C = A \cap C + B\cap C$$
I think that this equation does not hold. But I can't find the counterexapmle.
Please tell me the fact and some sufficient conditions of the above equation.

I understand the inclusion that $A \cap C + B\cap C \subseteq (A +B) \cap C$.

Work in $\mathbb{F}^2_2$ and consider $A=\langle(0,1)\rangle$,  $B=\langle(1,0)\rangle$, $C=\langle(1,1)\rangle$. Then you have $$(A+B)\cap C=C\neq \{0\}=A\cap C + B\cap C.$$
